# Error: this expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type int

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I am trying to do this simple while loop but it's not working. It is giving me the following error:

> this expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
> int

```
let function () = 
  let current = ref 0 in
  let square = ref !current in
  while(((square := !current * !current) mod 1000000) != 269696) do
    current := !current +1
  done;
  !square
;;
```

Comment: ``current := !current +1;`` : you have to put a **semicolon** after an unit instruction

Comment: @Butanium not in OCaml. The semicolon *separates* two unit instructions. No need to put one if no instruction follows.

Comment: Oh yes my bad I got too much synthax error because of semicolons missing x).
Anyway thanks for correcting me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `function` is a keyword in OCaml, you cannot use it to name your functions.
Also, the condition in the while loop is buggy:
this `square := !current * !current` is an assignment, which type is `unit`. It is a type error to use it as an argument of `mod` which takes two integers as input.

You should probably do the assignment inside the loop and only test `!square mod 1000000 <> 269696` in the loop's condition.
Notice that i used the `<>` structural inequality, instead of the physical one `!=` which by luck does the same thing for integers, but you should not use it unless you know that.